# Generating .XLS file as an output file of sqlplus query and sending that .XLS file as an attachment in email

Tags: bash, shell-script, mailx, sqlplus

I am generating output file (.xls format) from the below DB query-

```
sqlplus -S -L user/pass@DB <<EOF | sed '/^$/d' >> home/test/query_output.xls
set line 22000
set head off
set feedback off
SELECT * from table;
EOF
```

The `query_output.xls` file contains records as below-

```
VIM     00 34562356   22412299    Dated                                                    11-JUN-18  OMM  sansra carla     Yes No No No         02356478               14-SEP-18
```

To send this `query_output.xls` file as an attachment in email, I am using below-

```
uuencode home/test/ query_output.xls | mailx -s "Subject" me@Domain.com
```

Also tried

```
uuencode query_output.xls query_output.xls | mailx -s "Subject" me@Domain.com
```

But not getting the data in attachment received in email.

Also tried `mailx -a` and mutt but its showing 'illegal option -- a' and 'command not found' resp.

```
mailx -a home/test/query_output.xls -s "Subject" me@Domain.com < /dev/null

mutt -a query_output.xls query_output.xls < /dev/null
```

also tried

```
mailx -s "Subject" me@Domain.com < query_output.xls
```

but no attachment received.

Could you please help?

Comment: That's not an XLS format file.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an attachment with mutt like this:

```
"Body of email" | mutt -a query_output.xls  -s "subject" -- me@Domain.com
```